# Inject a MessageBox to the PE file

Tags: windows, pe, patching

I'd like to patch some `Windows PE` file to show just simple `MessageBox`. Taking into account that the `PE` in question doesn't import the `MessageBoxA` function if I'm right that all i need to do is to add the `user32.dll` to the `Imports Section` with `MessageBoxA` function. And then just patch the code (using `IDA` or `OllyDbg` or sth. similar) adding a `call` instruction to the address of the newly added `MessageBoxA` function from `Imports`? If I'm right that after adding a new entry to the `Imports` the `Windows Loader` automatically map the `MessageBoxA` function physical address to the virtual PE address space making the PE possible to call the needed function?

Comment: I believe LIEF will help you with patching. Check this documentation: https://lief-project.github.io/doc/latest/tutorials/02_pe_from_scratch.html

Comment: Well you're right about your import manipulation, yes. But a mere `call` won't help you. Depending on what the target is -- OllyDbg makes me assume x86 or x64, though -- you need to be aware of the calling convention(s) and pass the arguments in registers or on the stack accordingly. So it'd be some `mov` or `push` before the `call`, too.